# How to integrate ITK into Qt project?

Tags: qt, vtk, itk

I have been struggling to integrate ITKinto Qt project. I had Googled but i did not find anything helpful. I am trying to integrate it as it is Opencv. But I ended up with failure, can anyone tell me the correct process. Great thank if any proper references are provided.

Comment: What is the problem? I would suggest trying to build a very simple example (just #include "itkImage.h" and #include <QApplication> and see if it builds). If you can't get that to work, you'll have to show us what you've tried (your CMakeLists.txt file is probably the main part of what we need to see).

Comment: Hi,got a better way to do it. Instead of integrating ITK to Qt, which is a very long and brain eating process, the beter way is to integrate Qt & ITK together to Visual Studio and use them as individual blocks. It is much simpler. Any way @David Thanks for your responce, If any one needs to know the procedure please let me know.

Comment: Ohh I see what you're saying. Yes, there is really no reason to want to do that. You should just use both of those projects (ITK and Qt) from your client project separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to actually compile ITK INSIDE of Qt. You should just use both of those projects (ITK and Qt) from your client project separately.